# print out date ranges in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a sequential list of date range pairs, for weeks, months and fortnights, over the next year.

So for example, for weeks I would  need to have a date range 2/11/2015 - 08/11/2015, looping through for the rest of the year.

For months it would need to produce 01/11/2015 - 30/11/2015, looping through for the rest of the year.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What have you already tried to solve your own problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using ActiveSupport, Rails adds methods to Fixnum such as `#days`, `#weeks`, `#months`, `#fortnights`, and `#years`.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ef5144d8a5529baebdaf76dbf253d1d6f2d8689b/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ef5144d8a5529baebdaf76dbf253d1d6f2d8689b/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer/time.rb

The example below isn't perfect, because it doesn't take into account weird date cases (such as years that have 53 weeks). I'm sure others will have better solutions. You could also improve my solution below by breaking out of the loop once the date has exceeded `Date.today + 1.year`. I wanted to keep things simple for demo purposes.

```
(1..52).each_with_object([]) do |week_idx, memo| 
  memo << [Date.today + (week_idx - 1).weeks, Date.today + week_idx.weeks] 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
weeks_ary = Array.new
month_ary = Array.new
(Date.today..Date.today.next_year).each do |date|
    if date.wday == 1
        end_week = date + 6.days
        weeks_ary << "#{date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')} - #{end_week.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}"
    end
    if date.strftime('%d') == "01"
        month_ary << "#{date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')} - #{date.end_of_month.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}"
    end
end
#output:
# weeks_ary = ["02/11/2015 - 08/11/2015", "09/11/2015 - 15/11/2015", "16/11/2015 - 22/11/2015", "23/11/2015 - 29/11/2015", "30/11/2015 - 06/12/2015", "07/12/2015 - 13/12/2015", "14/12/2015 - 20/12/2015", "21/12/2015 - 27/12/2015", "28/12/2015 - 03/01/2016", "04/01/2016 - 10/01/2016", "11/01/2016 - 17/01/2016", "18/01/2016 - 24/01/2016", "25/01/2016 - 31/01/2016", "01/02/2016 - 07/02/2016", "08/02/2016 - 14/02/2016", "15/02/2016 - 21/02/2016", "22/02/2016 - 28/02/2016", "29/02/2016 - 06/03/2016", "07/03/2016 - 13/03/2016", "14/03/2016 - 20/03/2016", "21/03/2016 - 27/03/2016", "28/03/2016 - 03/04/2016", "04/04/2016 - 10/04/2016", "11/04/2016 - 17/04/2016", "18/04/2016 - 24/04/2016", "25/04/2016 - 01/05/2016", "02/05/2016 - 08/05/2016", "09/05/2016 - 15/05/2016", "16/05/2016 - 22/05/2016", "23/05/2016 - 29/05/2016", "30/05/2016 - 05/06/2016", "06/06/2016 - 12/06/2016", "13/06/2016 - 19/06/2016", "20/06/2016 - 26/06/2016", "27/06/2016 - 03/07/2016", "04/07/2016 - 10/07/2016", "11/07/2016 - 17/07/2016", "18/07/2016 - 24/07/2016", "25/07/2016 - 31/07/2016", "01/08/2016 - 07/08/2016", "08/08/2016 - 14/08/2016", "15/08/2016 - 21/08/2016", "22/08/2016 - 28/08/2016", "29/08/2016 - 04/09/2016", "05/09/2016 - 11/09/2016", "12/09/2016 - 18/09/2016", "19/09/2016 - 25/09/2016", "26/09/2016 - 02/10/2016", "03/10/2016 - 09/10/2016", "10/10/2016 - 16/10/2016", "17/10/2016 - 23/10/2016", "24/10/2016 - 30/10/2016", "31/10/2016 - 06/11/2016"]
# month_ary = ["01/12/2015 - 31/12/2015", "01/01/2016 - 31/01/2016", "01/02/2016 - 29/02/2016", "01/03/2016 - 31/03/2016", "01/04/2016 - 30/04/2016", "01/05/2016 - 31/05/2016", "01/06/2016 - 30/06/2016", "01/07/2016 - 31/07/2016", "01/08/2016 - 31/08/2016", "01/09/2016 - 30/09/2016", "01/10/2016 - 31/10/2016", "01/11/2016 - 30/11/2016"]
```